# Did scholars doubt Belshazzar's existence before 1854?

Tags: daniel, historical-criticism, babylon

I realise this isn't entirely related to hermeneutics, but anyway I was doing some research on people's views on King Belshazzar mentioned in Daniel 5. All the Christian apologists who defend the book of Daniel mention that his existence was disbelieved among the skeptical scholars up until 1854, when an archeological discovery of the Nabonidus cylinders confirmed his existence.

That figures, because prior to 1854, all the historians listed Nabonidus as the last King of Babylon. It may be an unusual and random question to ask, but I was wondering which scholars/historians are actually recorded explicitly stating that Belshazzar didn't exist?

Apparently German theologian Ferdinand Hitzig was one of them, websites mention that he said that Belshazzar was 'obviously a figment of the Jewish writer's imagination'. But I went to the source (his book is named Das Buch Daniel, which you can find here https://archive-org.translate.goog/stream/bub_gb_i5JAAAAAcAAJ/bub_gb_i5JAAAAAcAAJ_djvu.txt?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=sc), and when I did a search on the file I couldn't find where he said that, which is why other people say that the claim that Ferdinand made this quote is false.

Again, a random and seemingly unprofitable question, but yeah if anyone's interested, do help me out.

Comment: This question might be better off being migrated to Christianity Stack Exchange & slightly modified in the question & title.  Nevertheless, interesting question & topic.

Comment: If you search all book ref like this, on google books, you will get more specific ref on where he said that- https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=Ferdinand+Hitzig+Belshazzar&num=10

Comment: It's stunning how dismissive historians can be of historical documentation based on a lack of historical documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to Keaton Halley of [Creation Ministries International](https://creation.com/archaeology-belshazzar), scholars who doubted Belshazzar's existence include:

- Caesar von Lengerke, *Das Buch Daniel*, p. 204, Bornträger, Königsberg, 1835
- Ferdinand Hitzig, *Das Buch Daniel*, p. 75, Weidmann, Leipzig, 1850

The problem is that the linked translation of Hitzig's book is poor and the pagination numbers apparently do not match. Halley refers to a German edition. I did find this, although the English is garbled, on p. 37:

> *This entire dream image melts away before the reality factual truth that the second monarchy, even if she the Baltasar one does not have
> to be, the Medo-Persian one does not have to be no could.*

In any case, it seems to have been the general attitude of critical scholars to doubt Belshazzar's real existence prior to the discovery of the documents mentioned in the OP. In these scholars' defense, it should be mentioned that the fact of Belshazzar's historical existence did not effectively prove that the Book of Daniel is otherwise accurate in its account of Belshazzar. A lengthy article in the [Jewish Encylopedia](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/2846-belshazzar) summarizes:

> The following important differences between Belsharusur and the
> Belshazzar of Daniel are patent. The former was the son of the last
> king of Babylon, but never reigned, except possibly as coregent with
> his father; while the latter is distinctly called the last king and
> the son of Nebuchadnezzar, both of which statements are undoubtedly
> made in perfectly good faith by the author of Daniel.

[Halley's bio](https://creation.com/keaton-halley) at Creation Ministries contains several ways to get in touch with him to follow up regarding his citations. Let us know if you solve the mystery.

Comment: whoops, I didn't realize this was old post by a user that has since disappeared. Hopefully my answer will help somebody somewhere, sometime.

Comment: The translation linked by the OP is Google translating the original 1850 edition. Your quote from p. 37 seems entirely out of context, he opposes a specific interpretation of Daniel, not the historicity of Daniel itself. The actual page cited is [here](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_i5JAAAAAcAAJ/page/n88/mode/1up?view=theater) and his claim (which I read only in Google-translated English) seems to be correctly presented by Creation: "his name and story were invented" (the name Belshazzar was invented for Nabonidus and the story of Belshazzar=Nabonidus dying is false because he surrendered)